# Prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq\frac14$ for any non-negative seqence $\{a_n\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers. Prove that
> $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2\left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\right)\leq\frac14.$$

I found this problem on one of my old notebooks, and clearly I forgot where it came from. I searched using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Climinf_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Dn%5E2%5Cleft(4a_n%5Cleft(1-a_%7Bn-1%7D%5Cright)-1%5Cright)%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%24&p=1) and it led me to [a post on AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h578238p3410690) without solutions.

I have to admit that I don't know how to start. First of all, it is easy to notice that if we have a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ with $a_{n_k}\geq 1$ for all $k$, then we must have $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq0\leq \frac14$; also, the case where there are infinitely many $0$'s is easy to handle. So, WLOG we can assume that $a_n\in(0,1)$ for all $n$.

Secondly, notice that $4x(1-x)-1=-(2x-1)^2\leq 0$, with equality holds iff $x=\frac12$. It may suggest that $\frac12$ is an important number here. Now it seems natural to write $a_n=\frac12+b_n$, so we have $b_n\in(-1/2,1/2)$ and we want to prove that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(n^2(b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_nb_{n-1})\right)\leq\frac18.$$
But this is not obvious, either.

**Remark.** The bound $1/4$ (or $1/8$ in terms of $b_n$) is sharp. If we choose $b_n=-\frac1{4n}$, or equivalently $a_n=\frac12-\frac1{4n}$ for $n\geq1$, then
$$n^2(b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_nb_{n-1})=\frac{n^2}{8n(n-1)}\to\frac18,\qquad n\to\infty.$$

The above are simplest (kind of silly) observations.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but based on my experience jotting down pages of these types of notes, this proof would have come after some easier ones. Maybe you first proved something like $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left((4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq\frac14$$ and then $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq\frac14$$ and only then $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq\frac14.$$ Do you know how to do the first two? Maybe some methods from the proofs of the first two could help with a solution to the third one...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks for your comment. I tried for half an hour and I haven't proved even the first one.... I tried a contradiction argument. Taking the first one as an example: if it is not the case, then $a_n(1-a_{n-1})>\frac5{16}$ for $n$ large enough, hence $a_n>\frac5{16}+a_na_{n-1}>\frac5{16}+\frac5{16} a_{n-1}$ and..., but it didn't give a contradiction...   I believe that you're right, the proofs of the first two may help.

Comment: I managed to prove the first one. I will post it as a partial answer now. I'm not sure how to approach the second one.

Comment: This question is much more difficult than it is made out to be. Even I got the first statement, but @AdamRubinson I would like to see your partial solution anyway. I have an idea that I will try to implement, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I come up with this proof. Thanks to @Jack D'Aurizio, whose second thought is the main body of this proof; also thanks to @Adam Rubinson, some ideas formed during comunicating with whom also play an important role in this proof.

I'll divide the proof into $6$ steps, which may get readers startled at first glance. I just want to write things clearly, to make sure there is no mistake in every step. I hope that every line you'll see below is easy to understand. If there are mistakes somewhere, please let me know.

We are going to prove

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers. Prove that
> $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2\left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\right)\leq\frac14.\tag{1}$$

**Step 1.** In the first step, I'll reduce the choices of $\{a_n\}$ to $a_n\in(0,1)$ for all $n\geq 1$, as I did in OP. If we have a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ with $a_{n_k}\geq 1$ for all $k$, then $4a_{n_k+1}(1-a_{n_k})-1\leq 0$ for all $k$ and thus $(1)$ holds; also, the case where there are infinitely many $0$'s is easy to handle. So, WLOG we can assume that $a_n\in(0,1)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

**Step 2.** In this step we rewrite $(1)$ in terms of $b_n$, which is more convenient to deal with. Let $a_n=\frac12+b_n$, then we have $b_n\in(-1/2,1/2)$ and our aim is to prove
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(n^2\left(b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_nb_{n-1}\right)\right)\leq\frac18.\tag{2}$$
Fix an arbitrary $a>\frac18$, we will prove
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(n^2\left(b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_nb_{n-1}\right)\right)\leq a.\tag{3}$$
Indeed, if $(3)$ holds for all $a>\frac18$, then $(2)$ follows easily.

**Step 3.** Suppose that $(3)$ is not true for some $a>\frac18$ (we will get a contradiction in the end of the proof,) then there exists $N>0$ such that
$$b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_nb_{n-1}>\frac a{n^2},\qquad \forall n>N.\tag{4}$$
We may assume WLOG that $N=1$, so we have
$$b_n>\frac{b_{n-1}+\frac a{n^2}}{1-2b_{n-1}},\qquad \forall n\geq 2.\tag{5}$$
We claim that $b_n\leq 0$ for all $n\geq1$. Suppose $b_{n_0}>0$ for some $n_0\geq 1$, then it follows from $(5)$ that
$$b_n>\frac{b_{n-1}}{1-2b_{n-1}},\qquad \forall n\geq n_0+1.$$
By induction we can easily show that $b_n>0$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=n_0}^\infty$ is increasing. Recalling that $b_n<\frac12$ for all $n\geq1$, the limit $L:=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists and satisfies $0<b_{n_0}\leq L\leq \frac12$. Letting $n\to\infty$ in $(4)$, we get $-2L^2\geq 0$, which implies that $L=0$, a contradiction. This proves our claim that $b_n\leq 0$ for all $n\geq1$.

**Step 4.** Let $c_n=-2b_n$, then $c_n\in[0,1)$ for all $n\geq 1$ and
$$c_n<\frac{c_{n-1}-\frac{2a}{n^2}}{1+c_{n-1}},\qquad \forall n\geq2. $$
And we also have $c_n>\frac{2a}{(n+1)^2}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Define $\{d_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by $d_1=c_1$ and
$$d_n=\frac{d_{n-1}-\frac{2a}{n^2}}{1+d_{n-1}},\qquad \forall n\geq2. \tag{6}$$
Since the map $x\mapsto\frac{x-\frac{2a}{n^2}}{1+x}=1-\frac{1+\frac{2a}{n^2}}{1+x}$ is increasing for $x>0$, we can easily prove by induction that
$$\frac{2a}{(n+1)^2}<c_n\leq d_n,\qquad n\geq1.\tag{7}$$

**Step 5.** In this step we prove the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}nd_n$ exists and is finite. By $(7)$, we have $nd_n>0$ for all $n\geq1$. We prove that $\{nd_n\}$ is decreasing after finite terms. Indeed, for $n\ge 1$,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{(n+1)d_{n+1}}{nd_n}=\frac{(n+1)d_{n+1}-\frac{2a}{n+1}}{nd_n(1+d_n)}<1\\
\Longleftrightarrow& (n+1)d_{n+1}-\frac{2a}{n+1}<nd_n+nd_n^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow& nd_n^2-d_n+\frac{2a}{n+1}>0\\
\Longleftrightarrow& \left(d_n-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2+\frac{2a}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{4n^2}=\left(d_n-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2+\frac{(8a-1)n-1}{4n^2(n+1)}>0.
\end{align*}
Since $a>\frac18$, there eixsts $N>0$ such that
$$0<(n+1)d_{n+1}<nd_n,\qquad n>N.$$
Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} nd_n$ exists and is finite.

**Step 6.** In the final step, we deduce a contradiction. By $(6)$, we have
$$-n^2(d_{n+1}-d_n) = \frac{1}{1+d_n}\left(2a\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+(nd_n)^2\right),\qquad n\geq 1.$$
Assume $A:=\lim_{n\to\infty} nd_n$, then $0\leq A<\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=0$. By [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_0/0_case),
\begin{align*}
A&=\lim_{n\to\infty} nd_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d_n}{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_{n+1}-d_n}{\frac1{n+1}-\frac1n}\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(d_{n+1}-d_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+d_n}\left(2a\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+(nd_n)^2\right)\\
&=2a+A^2.
\end{align*}
However, since $a>\frac18$, there is no $A\in\mathbb R$ such that $A=2a+A^2$. $\color{red}{\text{This is a contradiction!}}$

So, the proof is completed now. I would like to express my gratitude to anyone who are reading this long post and answer. Comments or remarks on a easier proof, or improved results, or anything else related to this problem, are very welcome.

Comment: Great stuff here. I worked on this problem for a very short period , but all I obtained in that time was the $\sin^2$ substitution and a couple of other ideas. One was interesting and can perhaps still be implemented, although I'm not sure : for any such sequence $a_n\in (0,1)$ (after executing the first step), create a function out of $a_n$, say $\sum a_nx^n$ or something like that which will be $C^{\infty}$, and obtain general bounds on its growth using derivatives etc. : this approach wasn't very fruitful so I dropped it.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks for letting me know your ideas. That sounds intersting to me, to consider $\sum a_nx^n$, which I haven't thought before. Thanks for your efforts to this problem!

Comment: I *knew* Stolz-Cesaro could be used here somehow, but I have poor understanding of it(have only used it once)...

Comment: (+1) Great job!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wouldn't have happened without your help. Thanks again from the bottom of my heart!

Answer (score 5):

**Just some ideas**.

Given $a_n\in(0,1]$, let $a_n=\sin^2\theta_n$ for $\theta_n\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. We want to show that

$$ \liminf_{n\to +\infty} n^2\left(4\sin^2\theta_n\cos^2\theta_{n-1}-1\right)\leq\frac{1}{4} $$

i.e. that $\sin\theta_n\cos\theta_{n-1}=\sin\theta_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_{n-1}\right)$ is frequently close to $\frac{1}{2}$, precisely
$$ \sin\theta_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_{n-1}\right)\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n^2}}. \tag{1}$$

If $\theta_n\leq\frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\theta_{n-1}\geq \frac{\pi}{3}$ then $(1)$ is automatically fulfilled. It follows that we may assume $\theta_{n-1}<\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta_n>\frac{\pi}{6}$, so from some point on all the $\theta_n$s lie in the central part of $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Once this is settled, we have $\sin\theta_n \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, hence we may further restrict the $\theta_n$s to the interval $\left[\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\arccos\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$. Here the sine function is bounded by $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, allowing a further restriction to $\left[\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}},\arccos\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\right]$. Here the sine function is bounded by $\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}$, allowing a further restriction to $\left[\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}},\arccos\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\right]$.

I guess it is clear where I am headed here. We just have to prove that by performing this restriction process (bringing $\left[\arcsin\sqrt{a},\arccos\sqrt{a}\right]$ into $\left[\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1}{4(1-a)}},\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1}{4(1-a)}}\right]$) $N$ times we end up in a neighbourhood of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with a certain diameter, granting $(1)$ anyhow. More precisely, by studying the iterations of $f:a\mapsto\frac{1}{4(1-a)}$ we have the following: if $\sin\theta_n\cos\theta_{n-1}>\frac{1}{2}$ holds for any $n\leq N$, then for any $n>N+1$ we have that $\theta_n$ lies in the interval

$$\left[\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2N+2}},\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2N+2}}\right] $$
so $\sin\theta_{N+2}\cos\theta_{N+1}$ is at most $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2N+2}$. Unluckily, this only proves (since $N$ is arbitrary)
$$ \liminf_{n\to +\infty} \color{red}{n}(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\leq \color{red}{2}.$$

---

*Alternative approach*. Let us assume that
$$ b_n-b_{n-1}-2 b_n b_{n-1} > \frac{1}{8n^2} \tag{2}$$
holds for all values of $n$ from some point on: up to reindexing we may as well assume that $(2)$ holds for all $n\geq 1$. Let us study the solutions of

$$ b_n = \frac{b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8n^2}}{1-2 b_{n-1}} \tag{3}$$
for $n\geq 1$ and $b_0\in\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$. If $b_0>0$ then $b_n > \frac{b_{n-1}}{1-2 b_{n-1}}$ and $b_n\to +\infty$ violating the boundedness of $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$. Let us set $c_n=-b_n$ and consider
$$ c_n = \frac{c_{n-1}-\frac{1}{8n^2}}{1+2 c_{n-1}}\tag{4} $$
for $c_0\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Letting $2c_n=d_n$, we may as well study
$$ d_n = \frac{d_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4n^2}}{1+d_{n-1}}\tag{5} $$
for $d_0\in(0,1)$. If at some point $d_n$ becomes negative, the destiny of the sequence is to blow up. We want to show that the only chances are a blow up or $\lim n d_n=\frac{1}{2}$. Luckily, the recurrence
$$ \widetilde{d}_n = \frac{\widetilde{d}_{n-1}}{1+\widetilde{d}_{n-1}}$$
with $\widetilde{d}_0=d_0$ has a simple solution, $\widetilde{d}_n=\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{d_0}}$, leading to $d_n\leq \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{d_0}}$. It follows that as long as the sequence stays positive, $nd_n$ is bounded by one. By plugging these  inequalities back into $(5)$ it should be possible to achieve a good understanding of the asymptotic behaviour of the solutions of $(5)$. We may also notice that if the limit $\lim nd_n$ exists it is necessarily $\frac{1}{2}$ by Cesaro Stolz, since
$$ -n^2(d_{n+1}-d_n) = \frac{1}{1+d_n}\left(\frac{n^2}{4(n+1)^2}+(nd_n)^2\right).$$

Comment: +1. Nice change of variables! Thanks for your answer! I have a question... If I understood your answer correctly, you didn't use the part $\frac1{4n^2}$ in this proof. Does it mean that you have proved $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n^2(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\right)\leq0$??? I'm a liitle bit lost here.

Comment: @Feng: of course not. Every time we apply a "restriction step" we have to shift the indices by one, so in order to get $\left|\theta_n-\frac{\pi}{4}\right|\leq \frac{c}{M}$ we need $n\geq M$. The quadratic bound is a consequence of the last line with $\delta=\frac{c}{M}$, and it is a sharp bound by your last example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry for my late reply to you. I think I have understood your proof more than I did yesterday. As I see, you proved that for any $\delta>0$, we can WLOG asume that there exist $N>0$ such that $\theta_n\in (\pi/4-\delta,\pi/4+\delta)$ for all $n>N$. This will quickly prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\leq0$. But, forgive my silliness, I still don't know how your arguments imply $\liminf_{n\to\infty}n^2 \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq\frac14$, where $\frac14$ on RHS must be useful (I think).

Comment: You are right, my original argument only proves $$\liminf_{n\to +\infty}\color{red}{n}(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\leq\frac{1}{4}$$. I added a second line of attack which seems to get closer to the claim.

Comment: Thanks for your hard-working! I still can’t catch your idea on the final part of the first argument. How did you get $\liminf_{n\to +\infty} n(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\leq 2$ from $4a_n(1-a_n)\leq 4\left(\frac12+\frac1{2N+2}\right)^2$ for all $n>N+1$? I mean, when we take limit on $n$, the other number $N$ should be fixed.

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2N+2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2+o(1)}{N+1}} $$ and the restriction argument shows that $4\sin^2\theta_n\cos^2\theta_{n-1}\leq 1+\frac{2+o(1)}{n}$ holds infinitely often.

Comment: Now I think I have understood your first argument! Although I’m not perfectly sure about that. It is late in my local time. My brain may be too tired for this hard (but very interesting) problem. I’ll come back to this problem tomorrow morning. Thanks again from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: Now I'm sure that I totally get your first idea! Although I'm thinking something different with yours. I'm writing here a more logical (natural, or rigorous) way to prove $\liminf n(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\leq 2$. If $\sin\theta_n\cos\theta_{n-1}\leq1/2$ infinitely often, then the result follows easily. So, we assume WLOG that $\sin\theta_ n\cos\theta_{n-1}>1/2$ for all $n$. Now we prove: $\sin\theta_ n\cos\theta_{n-1}>1/2$ for all $2\leq n\leq 2N+3$ implies $\theta_{N+1},\theta_{N+2}\in\left(\arcsin\sqrt{1/2-1/(2N+2)},\arccos\sqrt{1/2-1/(2N+2)}\right)$. And thus $\liminf n(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1)\leq2$

Comment: First we start from $n=2$: $\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1>1/2$ and $\sin\theta_3\cos\theta_2>1/2$ imply $\theta_2\in(\pi/6, \pi/3)$ and then $\sin\theta_3>\sqrt{1/3}$, so $\cos\theta_3<\sqrt{2/3}$; $\sin\theta_4\cos\theta_3>1/2$ implies $\theta_3\in(\arcsin\sqrt{1/3},\frac\pi/3)$ and $\sin\theta_4>\sqrt{3/8}$; in this way we can show that $\theta_n\in(\arcsin\sqrt{1/2-1/(2n)}, \pi/3)$ for all $n\geq 2$. Now we begin with $n=2N+3$ and look back. Similarly we can prove $\theta_{2N+3-n}\in(\pi/6,\arccos\sqrt{1/2-1/(2n)})$ for all $n\geq1$. Combining these two "restrictions" gives the claim.

Comment: My point is that: Probably we cannot get $\theta_{N+1}\in(\arcsin\sqrt{1/2-1/(2N+2)}, \arccos\sqrt{1/2-1/(2N+2)})$ by only assuming $\sin\theta_n\cos\theta_{n-1}>1/2$ for all $n\leq \color{red}{N}$. We need to look forward from $n=2$ and then look back from $n=2N+3$ to get the desired bound for $\theta_{N+1}$.  Btw, your second thought is awesome! The convergence of $nd_n$ is a not easy task! If I were you, I would ask a new question about the convergence of $nd_n$. I really appreciate  your work! If we finally solve the whole problem, I will give you the first bounty I offer!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**. As discussed in the comments, here is a proof that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq\frac14:$

Suppose by way of contradiction that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right) > \frac14$. Then there are **finitely** many $a_n$ such that $4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1 \leq \frac14,\ $ i.e., $\ a_n(1-a_{n-1}) \leq \frac{5}{16}.$ This implies there are six consecutive members of $(a_n)$ which satisfy $\ a_n(1-a_{n-1}) > \frac{5}{16}.$ But it is not too difficult to show that this is impossible.

Suppose WLOG that for all $n\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}*,\ a_n(1-a_{n-1}) > \frac{5}{16}.$ In order for $a_2(1-a_1) > \frac{5}{16},$ we must have $a_2 > \frac{5}{16}.$ Since $a_3(1-a_2) > \frac{5}{16}$ and $a_2 > \frac{5}{16},$ we must have  $a_3 > \frac{5/16}{11/16} = \frac{5}{11}.$ Since $a_4(1-a_3) > \frac{5}{16}$ and $a_3 > \frac{5}{11},$ we must have $a_4 > \frac{5/16}{6/11} = \frac{55}{96}.$ Since $a_5(1-a_4) > \frac{5}{16}$ and $a_4 > \frac{55}{96},$ we must have $a_5 > \frac{5/16}{41/96} = \frac{30}{41}.$ Since $a_6(1-a_5) > \frac{5}{16}$ and $a_5 > \frac{30}{41},$ we must have $a_6 > \frac{5/16}{11/41} = \frac{205}{176}.$ Since $\ 1-a_6<0\ $ and $\ a_7\geq 0,\ a_7(1-a_6) \leq 0 < \frac{5}{16},$ a contradiction. Therefore  $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right) \leq \frac14.$

*It may not be $2,3,4,5,6,7,$ but my proof is easier to follow than if I wrote $N, N+1, N+2, N+3, N+4, N+5.$

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think it is better now.

Comment: I have a guess. I think this argument can be applied to a much more stronger statement: $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq0$. All we need is to prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq a$ for all $a>0$, where the key point should be related to the sequence defined by $A_{n+1}(1-A_n)=\frac{a+1}4$ and $A_1=\frac{a+1}4$, and we need to check that $A_N>1$ for some $N$. I think this may be true. But the general term formula for $A_n$ involves complex numbers, which makes things not obvious.

Comment: Oh. Now I know how to prove the fact $A_N>1$ for some $N$: Note that $A_{n+1}/A_n>1$ by the recurrence relation. If $A_n$ is bounded by $1$, then it is convergent, and the limit is denoted by $A$. Then $A$ must satisfies $A(1-A)=\frac{a+1}4$ and $A\in\mathbb R$, which is impossible. Therefore, now we have proved that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq0$. Is it right?

Comment: I did not seriously consider involving complex numbers. I want to do without them...

Comment: Forget about the complex numbers thing... I realized they are not needed anymore. See my last comment on your answer. How did my idea on proving $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq0$ look?

Comment: I don't follow what $A_n$ is, sorry

Comment: I mean, I want to prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\leq0$. We only need to prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\leq a$ for all $a\in(0,1)$. Now suppose $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1>a$, then there exists $N$ such that $4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1>a$ for all $n\geq N$. Now we have $a_N(1-a_{N-1})>(a+1)/4$, so $a_N>(a+1)/4=A_1$ and $a_{N+1}(1-a_N)>(a+1)/4$ implies $a_{N+1}>\frac{a+1}{4(1-A_1)}=A_2$ and so on... So, $a_{N+k}>A_{k+1}$ for all $k$. It suffices to show that $A_m>1$ for some $m$ and then we will get a contradiction, just like what you did. And I've checked that?

Comment: But isn't that exactly what I did in my proof (although I have written the details)? Or are you saying that it works for all $\frac{a+1}{4},$ not just $\frac{5}{16}$ ? I'm not sure how you prove it for all $\frac{a+1}{4}.$

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I said that your argument can be applied to show a stronger statement $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq0$... In this case we need to consider $\frac{a+1}4$, which is a little more general than $\frac5{16}$. Now I think I've expressed my mind well.

Comment: Why does $A_{n+1} > A_n$ ?

Comment: $A_{n+1}=\frac{a+1}{4(1-A_n)}$ by definition, so $A_{n+1}/A_n=\frac{a+1}{4A_n(1-A_n)}$. Since $4A_n(1-A_n)\leq 1$, we have $A_{n+1}/A_n\geq a+1>1$. Maybe I had a logic problem. I should have said "If $A_n<1$ for all $n$" before claiming $A_{n+1}>A_n$.

Comment: I think I start to see your earlier argument now, yes. I'm not 100% certain of it, but it seems to make sense. I don't know what to do for the original problem though as the $n^2$ term means we can't use your argument (as there is no "fixed point equation"). And if we try to use my argument in my answer above, but for the $n^2$ sequence, then I don't think we get anywhere...

Comment: I agree with you! And I didn't understand the whole proof by @Jack D'Aurizio. My understanding is that he only proved $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(4a_n(1-a_{n-1})-1\right)\leq0$, which is the same as what we've proved in these comments (Maybe adding what we did here to your existing answer is a good idea.)  As for the $n^2$ case, we may need a new method!